# What do you call it when one interface "inherits" from another?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

If I have
      class B : A   {}

I say that "Class B *inherited* class A" or "class B derives from class A".

However, if I instead have:

```
  class B : ISomeInterface   {}
```

it's wrong to say "B inherits ISomeInterface" -- the proper term is to say "B *implements* ISomeInterface".

But, say I have

```
  interface ISomeInterface : ISomeOtherInterface   {}
```

Now, it's still wrong to say "inherits", but it's now just as wrong to say "implements" since ISomeInterface doesn't implement anything.

So, what do you call that relationship?

Comment: Take your pick: http://thesaurus.reference.com/search?q=extend I personally like "ISomeInterface aggrandizes ISomeOtherInterface" :-)

Comment: So it is valid now to do what you are asking: interface ISomeInterface : ISomeOtherInterface ? Was this "implemented", if you excuse the pun, in the latest C# language spec (if so, from what version onwards?) wonder if i am still stuck in a time warp...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I personally say "extends" and I *thought* the C# spec uses that word as well somewhere (I can't find it now, unfortunately) - but I remember Eric Lippert saying he wasn't keen on it, and wanted to change it for 4.0.

I think it's good, because it shows that you're extending the contract specified by the original interface.

EDIT: Having looked at the 3.0 spec...

The spec sort of side-steps the issue in section 13.2. It talks about the members being inherited from the base interfaces. It talks about one *class* extending another, but not interfaces

EDIT: In the C# 5 spec, section 13.1.4, it uses inherits:

> An interface can inherit from zero or more interface types

So that's probably the best term to use.

Comment: Implements implys defining an implementation for an interface. Interfaces have no implementation so that's not possible here. But an interface can extend another interface, which means it can add more methods and inherit its type.

+1 for Extends

Comment: VB.Net uses the 'Inherits' keyword. It would be probably appropriate to use 'Inherits' when describing the same code in C#.

Comment: @BryanRayner: Have now found the appropriate bit of the C# 5 spec which uses inherits, too.

Comment: As always, asked  and a minute later got a full reply

Comment: But wouldn’t “inherit” imply that all of the members in the parent are accessible via the child interface’s type name (because inheritance implies transfer—or am I just reading the wrong English definition of the word)? In interfaces, that doesn’t happen—the parent’s members are always named (when implementing explicitly, for example) using the parent interface’s type. An interface listing parent interfaces merely creates a demand that any class implementing it also implement its parent interfaces.

Comment: @binki: Can you give any examples where it appears that the "child" interface doesn't inherit *except* explicit interface implementation? If I have a reference of type `IChild` I can call any members of the interface it inherits from, and if I'm implementing `IChild` I have to implement all the members of `IParent`. It feels to me like explicit interface implementation is the one part where it doesn't feel like inheritance.

Comment: Hmm, good point. When consuming an interface, it definitely feels like inheritance, especially since interfaces can hide parent members with the `new` keyword. I’d say maybe, uhh, multiple inheritance feels least like inheritance. If multiple parent interfaces specify members with the same name, the C# compiler raises an ambiguity error (CS0229) telling you that you have to choose which one of the interface’s parents you’re interested in. In that way, the members remain the part of the respective parent interface instead of becoming the child’s members—they sort of don’t inherit.

Comment: @binki: I think we'll have to agree to disagree. It seems like a reasonable use of the word to me, and it clearly *is* the word that the spec uses.

Answer (score 7):

I call it "extends".

Answer (score 7):

Usually, I call it overengineering.

Comment: INewerVersion extends IOlderVersion.  COldClass implements IOlderVersion but doesn't implement INewerVersion.  CNewClass implements INewerVersion.  Where's the overengineering?

Comment: @Windows programmer:  This is a good exception.  Hence, the **usually** overengineering.  First of all, this was somewhat tongue-in-cheek.  Secondly, when you have interfaces inheriting from interfaces, you've got at least three levels of inheritance because someone's going to implement those interfaces too.  That's starting to get up there.

Comment: So if we're trying to write "SOLID" code that pays homage to the "Interface Segregation Principle," without having every stream that can both read and write implement two separate interfaces, should IStream extend the combination of IReadableStream and IWriteableStream? Or is that "over engineering"? Sometimes I find myself thinking that a good programming project is like a good aircraft landing - you walk away from it.

Answer (score 6):

As an **authoritative source** and in case you need a helpful quote, I came across [info on MSDN](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979) that describes "**interface inheritance**" with a practical example of the interface inheritance structure for the ComboBox, Control, Listbox and TextBox:

And with mention of an explicit base interface

> **An interface can inherit from zero or more interfaces**, which are
> called the **explicit base interfaces** of the interface.

Example:

```
interface IControl
{
   void Paint();
}
interface ITextBox: IControl
{
   void SetText(string text);
}
interface IListBox: IControl
{
   void SetItems(string[] items);
}
interface IComboBox: ITextBox, IListBox {}
```

Source:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664578%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Why would it be wrong to say InterfaceB "inherits" or "derives from" InterfaceA? "Implements" would be wrong, because InterfaceB doesn't provide an implementation. Semantically, deriving interfaces is very similar to deriving classes.
C++, for example, doesn't distinguish between interfaces and classes at all.

Answer (score 1):

you've got the definition wrong.

B : A means "B inherits from A".

when we say "B implements InterfaceA", that usually means InterfaceA does not have the definition to function - it's only prototypes (or, PURE in C++). However in C++ and most OOPL, the inherit and implement shares same syntax.

So, InterfaceB : InterfaceA still means "InterfaceB inherits InterfaceA".