# Extension methods for both ICollection and IReadOnlyCollection

Tags: c#, icollection

I want to write an extension method (e.g. `.IsEmpty()`) for both ICollection and IReadonlyCollection interfaces:

```
public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this IReadOnlyCollection<T> collection)
{
  return collection == null || collection.Count == 0;
}

public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this ICollection<T> collection)
{
  return collection == null || collection.Count == 0;
}
```

But when I use it with classes implemeting both interfaces, I obviously get the ‘ambiguous invocation’.
I don't want to type `myList.IsEmpty<IReadOnlyCollection<myType>>()`, I want it to be just `myList.IsEmpty()`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you set one method for `IEnumerable<T>` instead? And btw. implementing both `ICollection<T>` and `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` in the same class seems a bit strange.

Comment: Many standard classes implement them both. E.g. `List<T>`, `Dictionary<T>` etc.

Comment: Either you give them different names or you put them in different static classes in different namespaces.

Comment: @mikez But you shouldn’t have to. Welcome to duck-typing and to MS mistakenly not having `ICollection<T>` implement `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` when the fact that [`List<T>` implements both `IList<T>` and `IReadOnlyList<T>` implies that it should](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15262988/429091).

Comment: @binki It's not a mistake, [it's intentional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12622784/247702). And interfaces don't implement other interfaces, [they inherit from other interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/807227/247702).

Comment: @Stijn I understand that it is necessary because of backwards compatibility concerns. But note that “reason #2” in the answer you linked is the incorrect misconception that read-only implies immutable. I may say that MS was mistaken because they shipped `ICollection<T>` before they thought of `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`. If .net were to start fresh and did not have a backwards compatibility concern, I’m quite sure they would not hesitate to make `ICollection<T>` be a `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`. I’m also not sure that you can say interfaces inherit either because the members stay with the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that they both inherit from `IEnumerable<T>` you could avoid the ambiguity issue by doing an extension on that instead:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        return enumerable == null || !enumerable.Any();
    }
}
```

Comment: `enumerable.Count() == 0` enumerates all the items in `enumerable`. It's better to use `!enumerable.Any()`.

Comment: True, I wanted to keep it simple, but that is a valid performance optimization. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This is not the *most* ideal solution if your extension’s implementation needed to know the `Count` of the collection. That property seems to be the one thing that both [`ICollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s3kzhec%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`IReadOnlyCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881496%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gain you over `IEnumerable<T>`. However, [the implementation of `Enumerable.Count<T>()` *will* try upcasting to `ICollection<T>` first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb338038%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), preventing most unnecessary enumeration.

Comment: As binki said, this is not the best approach.
For instance, string implements IEnumerable interface but is neither ICollection nor IReadOnlyCollection, and you don't want a string type be accepted by your generic function.