# If IQueryable<T> inherits IEnumerable<T> , how come IQueryable<T> is LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2015, ienumerable, iqueryable

`IEnumerable<T>` case is LINQ-to-object and `IQueryable<T>` is the interface that allows LINQ-to-SQL , however `IQueryable<T>` inherits `IEnumerable<T>` , so how is it possible to `IQueryable<T>` to filter rows in the Database while `IEnumerable<T>` filters objects in the memory ?

Comment: See if this article helps: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/02/20/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-43-out-of-process-queries-with-iqueryable/

Comment: *IQueryable<T>* Note that there is no guarantee that a `IQueryable<T>` is database-based. The specific class implementing `IQueryable<T>` specifies how the data is retrieved. From a DB, from Internet, from memory (`.AsQueryable()`)...

Comment: Note that Linq-toSQL is a specific (dead-end) product. Most IQueryables will be implemented by Entity Framework.

Answer (score 8):

You are mistaking inheritance and interface implementation.

`IQueryable<T>` inherits `IEnumerable<T>` but that is *radically different from inheritance between classes* where the derived class inherits the *implementation* of the base class. Interfaces are simply contracts, there is no actual code behind them:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Foo(); //its simply a contract, no implementation at all.
}

public interface IBar: IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}

public class Foo: IFoo
{
    void Foo() { //Foo's sepecific implementation goes here }
}

public class Bar : IBar 
{
    void Foo() { //Bar's specific implementation goes here }
    void Bar() { //implementation goes here }
}
```

The fact that `Bar` implements `IFoo` through `IBar` doesn't mean, in any way, that there is any relationship whatsoever between `Foo` and `Bar`.

Comment: The first line isn't entirely on point. IQueryable and IEnumerable could have been base classes with the same effect. Just awkward for the rest of you class diagram.

Comment: How can `IQueryable<T>`, an interface, implement anything?

Comment: @Rawling another interface? What is the correct wording if it's not implement? I'm. I'm not native English. Defines?

Comment: Apparently the correct wording [*is* inheriting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22955789/215380). Implementing is providing the actual code for the methods.

Comment: Standard terminology is to Implement an Interface, being just a contract and no code of its own

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - apply that to `IQueryable : IEnumerable` .

Comment: @MrinalKamboj A class implements an interface.  An interface *inherits* another interface.

Answer (score 3):

> how is it possible to IQueryable to filter rows in the Database while IEnumerable filters objects in the memory ?

They don't, that is an inaccurate statement.

The actual implementation code is inside extension methods which are selective for either IEnumerable or IQueryable.

In EF there is a

```
Where<T>(this IQueryable<T>, Expression<Predicate<T>> )
```

and in System.Linq there is

```
Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T>, Predicate<T>)
```

The resoluton rules will prefer an IQueryable extension over the basic Linq one, and the magic is enabled through the `Expression<>` parameter.