# Restricting public interface implementations to internal use only

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, internal

I have an internal interface which inherits/[extends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807217/what-do-you-call-it-when-one-interface-inherits-from-another) a public interface:

```
internal interface IFoo: IList<string>
{
    void FooAdd(string item);
}
```

I only want to allow internal access to the members of `IFoo` and, by extension, `IList<string>`. Direct members of `IFoo` can be implemented with the `internal` keyword, but since `IList<T>` is public, I have to implement them explicitly:

```
public class MyClass: IFoo, IReadOnlyList<string>
{
    // IFoo implementations:
    internal void FooAdd(string item)
    {
        ...
    }

    // Explicit IList<string> implementations:
    void IList<string>.Add(string item)
    {
        ...
    }

    // Public IReadOnlyList<string> members:
    public int Count { get { return ... } }
}
```

Now, since the `IFoo` interface is internal, users of my lib cannot access the implemented methods that are declared `internal` in `MyClass`, which is what I intended. However, they can still access `IList<T>` members by casting, which I did not expect:

```
var myClassObj = new MyClass<string>();
(myClassObj as IList<string>).Add("Haha, gotcha!");
```

Outside the library, I would have expected that the compiler would complain that there is no way to cast `myClassObj` to an `IList<string>`, since `MyClass` only implements this interface through an internal interface.

Is there a different pattern I should use, if I want my class to implement public interface functionality, that should only be available internally?

Comment: Direct members of IFoo **cannot** be implemented with the internal keyword, you'd get a compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would have expected that the compiler would complain that there is no way to cast `myClassObj` to an `IList<string>`

The compiler has no way to do that. Except in very limited scenarios, the compiler treats explicit casts and conversions deferentially, with the assumption that since you wrote it, you meant it. It's not hard to write code where a cast will always fail at run-time, even though the compiler allowed it and even though you could look at the code and see that it will always fail.

To see why, consider that your object could always be referenced by a variable of type `object`. When that happens, the compiler has no knowledge of the declared implementation of the object. It can't prevent a cast in the code, even if the cast is known to be illegal.

And of course, at run-time the only thing that matters is whether the object actually *does* implement the interface. So the cast isn't even illegal anyway. Explicit interface implementation doesn't hide the interface. It just imposes the requirement that the implementation can't be used except through an expression of that interface type. It's not a means of controlling accessibility at all.

If you don't want outside code to see your `IList<T>` implementation in an object that the outside code has access to, then you have to actually *hide* it from that code. The only way to do that is to change your design so that your object *has* an `IList<T>` instead of *is* an `IList<T>` (i.e. composition vs. inheritance), and that `IList<T>` is accessible only to the code you want (e.g. exposed by a property marked `internal`).

Do keep in mind that even then, accessibility is primarily a compile-time safety feature. Reflection in a full-trust environment (i.e. in the context the vast majority of managed code executes) will always allow access to whatever code has access to the object in the first place, regardless of accessibility. It's good to restrict access, for the purpose of encouraging correct usage of your types, but it's not a security feature per se (though it can be used in conjunction with such).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and I agree 100% with your last paragraph; I only intend to restrict code access to ensure correct usage. Regarding the first 3 paragraphs, I was hoping that the compiler would throw a [CS0039](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0039) error, but I do see your point that composition is probably better suited in this case.

Comment: CS0039 is emitted only when the compiler can guarantee that the cast will fail. Of course, that's not the case here since, as I described, it's not actually illegal to cast your object to a public interface it implements.

Comment: *Reflection will always allow access to whatever code has access to the object in the first place, regardless of accessibility.* Can you provide reference for this? AFAIK, attempt to access to inaccessible member will generate demand for `ReflectionPermission`, which cause `SecurityException` when caller can not satisfy demand.

Comment: @PetSerAl: you seem confused by the semantics of my statement. Reflection always allows access, but the caller may not always have access to reflection. It's like saying "one can always get ice from my freezer", which is true even if some particular person doesn't have access to my freezer (e.g. I didn't let them into my house). If you have some different wording you think would be better, feel free to suggest something.

Comment: As far as I understand, in current .NET Framework version access to Reflection is always allowed. You can freely enumerate all members, including inaccessible ones, and call to any accessible member. Calling to inaccessible members is restricted. So, unless you mess-up with permission assignment and assign very sensitive permissions to partially trusted code, it have no way to access inaccessible members. Member accessibility is not compile-time only feature. It is security feature that also enforced at run-time, but if you grant someone `FullTrust` permission, then them can bypass it.

Comment: @PetSerAl: I don't think we disagree, but maybe my wording was careless. I've edited the post to clarify my intent.